# ordered pair double intersection is equal to first member?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\cap \cap (a,b)=a$.

As far as I know $\cap (a,b)=a$, why would they add another $\cap$?

Answer (score 3):

With $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ we only have $\bigcap (a,b)=\{a\}\cap\{a,b\}=\{a\}\ne a$.

Comment: Is it necesary that we let $a$ be a set?

Comment: @JoséOsorio Not really. But in set theory, everything is a set.